# SQL Error on main forum list page

Tags: 7, nodes

I've just activated the Forum module and installed Advanced Forum. My 3 forums and 2 containers work when I browse straight to the forums and containers. The main list doesn't work though. When I go to /forum I get a SQL Error

> General Error
>   SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]
>
> Access denied for user 'username'@'hostname.com' (using password: YES) [1045]
>
> An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists.

Isn't the main forum page supposed to list all the containers and forums like this http://drupal.org/forum? Do I have to enable anything or make a main container to make it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the user you set in your settings.php file doesn't have access to the database, which could happen because the password you wrote in that file is not the correct one.

Any Drupal module that accesses the database is using the [database API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7), which doesn't require any username or password, as those are taken from a file that Drupal reads during its bootstrap.
The Forum and the Advanced forum modules are not an exception. If you are getting that error, it means there is an error with the settings.php file, or a problem with the database server.

Comment: Shouldn't the settings.php file be ok since  the forums themselves work fine? I can go to /forum/86 and /forum/85 and see the forums and post in them. It's just the main /forum page that gives an error.

Comment: Found my dumb problem. Already had a forum folder with previous software installed that was creating issues when I went to /forum. You're answer made me look in other places so I guess it's the answer.